pipline: hudson.AbortException: No such saved stash ‘allure-results’
I am very convinced that it was normal for execution a few months ago, but now I report an error. I have a long time to investigate the error.
pipeline {
    agent any
    options { disableConcurrentBuilds() }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            agent { dockerfile true }
            steps {
                sh 'pytest -n auto --dist loadgroup --alluredir=allure-results --clean-alluredir'
                stash name: 'allure-results',includes: 'allure-results/*'
            }
        }
    }
    post('Report') {
        always {
            script {
                if (fileExists("allure-results")) {
                    sh 'rm -rf allure-results'
                }
                unstash 'allure-results'
                allure includeProperties: false, jdk: '', report: 'allure-report', results: [[path: 'allure-results']]
            }
        }
    }
}

enter image description here
I tried to put it in the same stage, but unfortunately did not take effect

Your log doesn't show if any files were stashed. Do you use Artifact Manager on S3 or something similar?
